# HTML code for INR

Tags: html

For pound (£) there is HTML code `&pound;`.

For [INR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee) can you please tell me the HTML code?

Comment: Refer: [Comprehensive Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643800/2142994)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the following HTML snippet:

```html
<p>Price &#x20b9; 9500 = &#x20b9; 9500</p>
<p>Price &#8377; 5500 = &#8377; 5500</p>
<p>Price &#8360; 500 = &#8360; 500</p>
<p>Price &#x20a8; 2000 = &#x20a8; 2000</p>
```

Answer (score 20):

₹​ Indian rupee sign. HTML: `&#8377;` — ₹ or `&#x20B9;` — also ₹, corresponding to Unicode U+20B9.

Answer (score 7):

Please try this -

INR (₹) sign HTML Code - `&#x20B9;`

Answer (score 6):

The indian rupee sign is pretty new (introduced [this July](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign) if I read it correctly) and doesn't even have a Unicode position yet, much less a HTML entity.

Even when it gets a Unicode position, it will probably still take years until it can be reliably used on a web page, because the client computers' Fonts will need to be updated accordingly. (I could imagine a `font-face` workaround with a custom font, though.)

Wikipedia uses an image file to display the symbol. It's far from good, but it may be the best workaround at the moment.

The generic rupee sign has three Unicode characters. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_rupee_sign).

Answer (score 5):

No! You should [avoid using HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities).

Instead of using HTML entities for symbols you should just put those symbols directly into your text and correctly [encode your document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).

- Instead of using `&pound;` you should use the character `£`.
- For rupee there is no Unicode character. You can use a PNG file instead [image: rupee]. Alternatively you can use the unicode character `रू` which is currently the most commonly used single character for rupee. Other alternatives are using `INR`, `Rs.` or `rupees`.

When the new Unicode symbol for the Indian Rupee is introduced then could use that instead (but note that it will be a while before all browsers support it).

Comment: Note that the Indian rupee has a distinct symbol by now, but it is not yet encoded into Unicode. Therefore this advice, while generally correct, doesn't really help in this case.

Comment: @Johannes Röseel: +1 Good point. I added that. :) I think while my advice is generally correct but not relevant in this case, I still hope it will not be completely ignored by the OP. Every useful advice can still be a good thing, even if it is not a direct answer. :)

Comment: Well, it will be valid in a few months ;-). The UTC has a meeting in late August or September, I think where quick-encoding the Indian Rupee sign will certainly be discussed. A proposal has already been submitted.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: True but be careful though: Not all browsers will support the new character immediately. You should check first that the major browsers all support the new character before deciding to use it.

Comment: The browsers (or applications in general) aren't the problem – they simply tell the rendering engine to render a specific code point; the fonts are. But it worked well enough for the Euro symbol (€) and this time we don't even have the problem to add the new symbol to legacy encodings.

Comment: @Joannes Rössel: True but the *real problem* here is trying to using HTML entities in the first place. I really think that this practice should be discouraged in new code. I am sure that the OP will ignore my advice. But I hope at least one person searching on Google reads this...

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: After thinking about it I think I will delete this answer and submit it as a comment instead... that way maybe at least the OP will see it and at the same time it will avoid adding noise to the answers. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Imho, you can leave this answer here. It's still a good point and I think our discussion here doesn't hurt either. The votes on the answers still make sure it doesn't add that much answer noise, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for Indian rupee sign:

`&#2352;` — र

Comment: This is wrong.  2352 decimal corresponds to hexadecimal 0x0930, but U+0930 is DEVANAGIRI LETTER RA.  The official rupee symbol is in the currency symbols set: U+20B9 INDIAN RUPEE SIGN.  The decimal representation is 8377, hence `&#8377;` or `&#x20B9;` is correct.

Comment: but am already use this code for indian currency and its working fine for me that why i post here http://linux.lexolutionit.com/vishnupriya/

Comment: OK: then your HTML coding is then over 3 years out of date. The formal currency symbol for Indian rupees has been U+20B9 since sometime in 2010.  The correct modern HTML code should use U+20B9.  If you are worried about old software that might not have a glyph for U+20B9, then in India, U+0930 may well be a good alternative (I'm not from India; I can't pontificate on that), but internationally it might be more sensible to use INR, the ISO standard code for the currency — analogous to USD or GBP (US dollars, British pounds).

Comment: One of the other answers suggests that U+0930 DEVANAGIRI LETTER RA plus U+0942 DEVANAGIRI VOWEL SIGN UU (which yields the glyph combination रू ) was used before U+20B9 became available.  Again, I can't help with whether that is definitive.  The biggest problem, though, is that you added your answer over 3 years after the question was asked, and you didn't provide new information that was compellingly different from the other answers, nor an explanation of why your answer was compellingly different.

Comment: This is outdated. This should be used instead. HTML ```&#8377;``` Unicode ```U+20B9```

Answer (score 3):

How about using fontawesome icon for Indian Rupee (INR).

Add font awesome CSS from CDN in the Head section of your HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And then using the font like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

just add &#8377 with semicolon where ever you want to display the rupee sign it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more example based on **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)** native api.

```js
var number = 123456.789;

// India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'INR',
  // limit to six significant digits (Possible values are from 1 to 21).
  maximumSignificantDigits: 6
}).format(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign), the new rupee sign hasn't been added to Unicode yet (*U+20B9 ₹ was added to Unicode in late 2010*), so you can't use it from HTML. The old (unofficial) symbol is &#x20a8; — ₨.

Answer (score 0):

Use similar symbol: `<del>&#2352;</del>` => <del>र</del>

Try `&#8377;` => ₹

Use an image(bad solution but works): `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGbfO.png" width="8" height="10">` => [image]

Source: [Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643675/empty-rectangle-box-is-displaying-instead-rupee-symbol-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use <del>र</del> => र ,but this is not professional way.
I recommend that you should use fontawesome

Answer (score -1):

SPAN class code.
Stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">
```

Now use the below mentioned code to type Indian Rupee symbol,

```
<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span>
```

Once the popular font families will be updated to Unicode 6.0.0, then you will be able to type Indian Rupee Symbol by typing ₹ in HTML editor.