# Need to add Indian Rupee Symbol in Zencart

Tags: php, shopping-cart, zen-cart

I want to add **INR symbol** in my currency listing in zencart.
I tried newly arrived hex code for it , but it wont work because not supported by every one , I know other way to add rupee symbol , site known as **webrupee.com** provide certain js to do so.
Any one can assist me how can i add rupee symbol to zencart ?

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430242/html-code-for-inr

Comment: Thanks @AJweb , I also know many ways to add rupee symbol.But in zen cart , I wanted to know if there is something that will help me.For not webrupee seems best option,need to experiment on it.

Answer (score 2):

Fine tutorial :

http://www.blogadr.com/tutorials/free-zen-cart-tutorial/zencart_admin_currency.html

go to localization -> Currencies -> Add new currency and exchange rate.

Comment: I know how to add currency , I need to know how to see new rupee symbol instead of RS.

Comment: ADD <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font"> in your email template and main template. add <span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span> as sysbol in zen cart admin panel.

Comment: No , it just add R to database , it filters tag.

Comment: update db table "zen_currencies" -> update"code" field char(3) to varchar(50) and set code value = '<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span>' for Rs.

Answer (score 0):

i got to work this in my store 
Assuming you have created rupee currency in zencart admin and save your database
next open your

1. MySql database
2. find currencies table and open it
3. you find all basic currencies
4. find the rupee currency you had created and you can find symbol
   field
5. replace the Rs. with   ₹   (copy paste this symbol) and save your
   database.

it is working fine for me - I will try and do a video.