# How to call Google font API to force display Rupess Sign

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, google-font-api

Hi I have an requirement to display Rupess sign but since most of the system won't support rupess font so i have gone through google font API and got css but don't know how to display Rupess symbol with google supported css . simply how to to display Rupess symbol with Google font css supportted . Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<span  id="rupess">Rs.</span>
</body></html>
```

Comment: use the unicode for it `&#8377`

Comment: I have used this unicode but it was showing as box because system won't support Rupees font so that's why i used google font css .

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal  Can you check my code and let me know what i am missing ?

Comment: try `<span style="font-family:Hind" id="rupess">&#8377</span>`

Comment: @JaromandaX : It's displaying but can you please elaborate is it taking for google imported css .

Answer (score 0):

Please user & #x20b9; (removeing the blank space after & sign ) for rupee sign.
For more details please read the answers of [HTML code for INR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430242/html-code-for-inr)

Comment: @Hossain :  i know this thing since system doesn't have regualr font so that's why using google font API  . but don't know how to use that API and display Rupess Symbol

Comment: Have you tried to use font-family in you css file, like
#rupess {
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;;
}