# How to get numbers to Indian rupees format in web page like 10,000.00

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I make it make when I enter the number it comes with Indian rupees format and the result also pastes on the total input box in the Indian rupees format? 
Please help with this.

```
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
<input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```

Here the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML code for INR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430242/html-code-for-inr)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037165/displaying-a-number-in-indian-format-using-javascript ?

Comment: @PrerakSola no i am asking for comma after three digits like when i enter the 10000 number it should be in 10,000.00 format that is my issue.

Comment: @EponymeWeb could you please edit given script for that format, i am struggling to do that

Comment: @Chiru — please check my answer :).

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore Yes you post the correct answer, Thank you.. Thank yo so much

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore And i have another doubt how We make same format For This   $(function() {
    $("#total, #total1").on("keydown keyup", sum);
 function sum() {
 $("#subt").val(Number($("#total").val()) - Number($("#total1").val()));
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Intl.NumberFormat` method to handle it all for you pretty much, I've created the demo below.

It's similar to your existing code, except it passes the values through the number formatter first.

```js
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'INR',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
//formatter.format(2500); /* $2,500.00 */
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = formatter.format(tot);
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
<input onkeyup="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
```

For browser support, please see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to get the string in INR currency format:

```js
function formatINR(x){
  return x.toLocaleString('en-IN');
}

var testString = 123342;
alert(formatINR(testString));
```

Comment: how to do the same format For Given Script    `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#total, #total1").on("keydown keyup", sum);
 function sum() {
 $("#subt").val(Number($("#total").val()) - Number($("#total1").val()));
 }

});
    </script>`

Comment: Try this: `$("#subt").val((Number($("#total").val()) - Number($("#total1").val())).toLocaleString('en-IN'));`

Comment: if you have any idea for converting Indian rupees format to word like when i enter 10,000 that shows ten thousand i have the script that gives result as like ten lacks. please give some idea or script

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is simple way

```
function toIndianRs($number ) {
  return (isNaN(parseInt($number))) ?  0 : /*'₹' + */ parseInt($number).toLocaleString('en-IN')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As already shown ( I had already started so... ) the `Intl.NumberFormat` method has lots of flexibility when dealing with all manner of numbers. A re-written demo below shows how it might be used and removes the horrible inline function calls '-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Indian Rupees</title>
        <style>
            form{
                width:50%;float:none;margin:2rem auto;padding:1rem;box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            form > input{
                width:100%;padding:1rem;margin:0.25rem;box-sizing:border-box;
            }
            output{
                display:block;width:50%;padding:1rem;box-sizing:border-box;float:none;margin:1rem auto;text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            /*
                https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat
            */
            const formatcurrency=function(i){
                return new Intl.NumberFormat( 'hi-IN', { style:'currency', currency: 'INR' } ).format( parseFloat( i ) );
            };



            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){
                let out=document.querySelector('output');
                let col=document.querySelectorAll( 'form > input[name="qty[]"]' );


                col.forEach( input => {
                    input.addEventListener( 'blur', function(e){
                        let total=0;
                        col.forEach( function(e){
                            if( e.value ) total += parseFloat( e.value )
                        });
                        out.innerText=formatcurrency( total );
                    }, false );
                } )
            },false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <output></output>
        <form>
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
            <input type='number' name='qty[]' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```