# Do I need to use HTML entities for special characters if I'm using the UTF-8 charset?

Tags: html, character-encoding

A site I'm working on is switching from ISO. If the HTML character set is set to UTF-8, do I still need to replace `©`, `é`, `…`, etc with the appropriate HTML entity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When Should One Use HTML Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, symbols like `©`, `é`, `…`, the German umlauts `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `ß` and all the other stuff can be used just like any other character when using UTF-8.

But note that some things still have to be entities because they have a special meaning in HTML ( `<` and `>` for example, which should still be replaced with `&gt;` and `&lt;` if you want to use them in your text)

Comment: Thanks. What about HTML emails? I assume I don't have the same control over character encoding there as I do on my own site, so should I use entities just to be safe?

Comment: you can give a header to define a charset in an html-mail, too - but some (mostly older) mail-clients will ignore that. best way is, like you said, to use entities in html-mails just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

in short : No you don't, actually I would even advise not to use them anymore. A possible legacy usage would be in some html pages links and forms "gets", but even here usually we can deal without.

Answer (score 1):

Depends also on how you generate / edit your content. If you have users editing files locally on Windows and what not, it may be safer to stick to entities after all.