# Display a dollar sign inside a code span using maven site and markdown

Tags: maven, markdown, maven-site-plugin, doxia

I would like to display a dollar sign inside a code span generated with maven-site-plugin and markdown (doxia-module-markdown).

Out of a code span, I used the numerical code `&#36;` and it fixed the issue.
But inside a code span (4 spaces), the numerical code is not decoded, which is actually not suprising :

> Within a code block, ampersands (&) and angle brackets (< and >) are
>   automatically converted into HTML entities.

(from http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code)

I also tried to double the dollar sign (`$$`), escape it (`\$`), charm it (`<3$`), but nothing worked!

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: +1 I love your effort to charm the dollar.

Comment: Also, are you sure you need to be escaping a dollar elsewhere on your page? Unless it's a special character for doxia (which I didn't think it was), then it [might not be necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a raw dollar sign within a code block. There is even a small example of this in the [doxia syntax page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

> Blockquotes can contain other Markdown elements, including headers, lists, and code blocks:

```
> ## This is a header.  
>   
> 1.   This is the first list item.  
> 2.   This is the second list item.  
>   
> Here's some example code:  
>   
>     return shell_exec("echo $input | $markdown_script");
```

In the example above, the dollars are unescaped.

Comment: Hi Duncan. Actually it works in a code block most of the time. But not for :
"$.fn." : the dollar sign disappears. 
I had to add a ugly space after the "$" sign ("$ .fn.") to prevent it from disappearing ! Any explanation ?

Comment: You can find an example [here](http://datatables4j.github.com/docs/advanced.extrafile.html#example--custom-row-filtering)