# Normalization on utf8 filenames stored in JSON with perl

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

I have two Json files which come from different OSes.

Both files are encoded in `UTF-8` and contain `UTF-8` encoded `filenames`.

One file comes from OS X and the filename is in NFD form: (`od -bc`)

```
0000160   166 145 164 154 141 314 201 057 110 157 165 163 145 040 155 145
           v   e   t   l   a    ́  **   /   H   o   u   s   e       m   e
```

the second contains the same filename but in NFC form:

```
000760   166 145 164 154 303 241 057 110 157 165 163 145 040 155 145 163
           v   e   t   l   á  **   /   H   o   u   s   e       m   e   s
```

As I have learned, this is called 'different normalization', and there is an CPAN module `Unicode::Normalize` for handling it.

I'm reading both files with the next:

```
my $json1 = decode_json read_file($file1, {binmode => ':raw'}) or die "..." ;
my $json2 = decode_json read_file($file2, {binmode => ':raw'}) or die "..." ;
```

The read_file is from `File::Slurp` and decode_json from the `JSON::XS`.

Reading the JSON into perl structure, from one json file the filename comes into `key` position and from the second file comes into the `values`. I need to search when the hash `key` from the 1st hash is **equvalent** to a `value` from the second hash, so need ensure than they are "binary" identical.

Tried the next:

```
 grep 'House' file1.json | perl -CSAD -MUnicode::Normalize -nlE 'print NFD($_)' | od -bc
```

and

```
 grep 'House' file2.json | perl -CSAD -MUnicode::Normalize -nlE 'print NFD($_)' | od -bc
```

produces for me the same output.

Now the questions:

- How to **simply** read both json files to get the same *normalization* into the both `$hashrefs`?

or need after the `decode_json` run someting like on both hashes?

```
while(my($k,$v) = each(%$json1)) {
    $copy->{ NFD($k) } = NFD($v);
}
```

In short:

- How to read different JSON files to get the same normalization 'inside' the perl `$href`? It is possible to achieve somewhat nicer as explicitly doing `NFD` on each `key` `value` and creating another NFD normalized (big) copy of the hashes?

Some hints, suggestions - pleae...

Because my english is very bad, here is a **simulation** of the problem

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use feature qw(unicode_strings);
use charnames qw(:full);
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Encode qw(encode decode);
use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFD NFC);

use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS;

#Creating two files what contains different "normalizations"
my($nfc, $nfd);;
$nfc->{ NFC('key') } = NFC('vál');
$nfd->{ NFD('vál') } = 'something';

#save as NFC - this comes from "FreeBSD"
my $jnfc =  JSON::XS->new->encode($nfc);
open my $fd, ">:utf8", "nfc.json" or die("nfc");
print $fd $jnfc;
close $fd;

#save as NFD - this comes from "OS X"
my $jnfd =  JSON::XS->new->encode($nfd);
open $fd, ">:utf8", "nfd.json" or die("nfd");
print $fd $jnfd;
close $fd;

#now read them
my $jc = decode_json read_file( "nfc.json", { binmode => ':raw' } ) or die "No file" ;
my $jd = decode_json read_file( "nfd.json", { binmode => ':raw' } ) or die "No file" ;

say $jd->{ $jc->{key} } // "NO FOUND";    #wanted to print "something"

my $jc2;
#is here a better way to DO THIS?
while(my($k,$v) = each(%$jc)) {
    $jc2->{ NFD($k) } = NFD($v);
}
say $jd->{ $jc2->{key} } // "NO FOUND";    #OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching the right solution for your question i discovered: the software is c*rp :) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448888/632407 .

Anyway, found the solution for your particular question - how to read json with filenames regardless of normalization:

instead of your:

```
#now read them
my $jc = decode_json read_file( "nfc.json", { binmode => ':raw' } ) or die "No file" ;
my $jd = decode_json read_file( "nfd.json", { binmode => ':raw' } ) or die "No file" ;
```

use the next:

```
#now read them
my $jc = get_json_from_utf8_file('nfc.json') ;
my $jd = get_json_from_utf8_file('nfd.json') ;
...

sub get_json_from_utf8_file {
    my $file = shift;
    return
      decode_json      #let parse the json to perl
        encode 'utf8', #the decode_json want utf8 encoded binary string, encode it
          NFC          #conv. to precomposed normalization - regardless of the source
            read_file  #your file contains utf8 encoded text, so read it correctly
              $file, { binmode => ':utf8' } ;
}
```

This should (at least i hope) ensure than regardles what decomposition uses the JSON content, the `NFC` will convert it to precomposed version and the JSON:XS will read parse it correctly to the same internal perl structure.

So your example prints:

```
something
```

without traversing the `$json`

The idea comes from Joseph Myers and Nemo ;)

Maybe some more skilled programmers will give more hints.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it may be important right now only to convert a few file names to the same normalization for comparison, other unexpected problems could arise from almost anywhere if JSON data has a different normalization.

So my suggestion is to normalize the entire input from both sources as your first step before doing any parsing (i.e., at the same time you read the file and before `decode_json`). This should not corrupt any of your JSON structures since those are delimited using ASCII characters. Then your existing perl code should be able to blindly assume all UTF8 characters have the same normalization.

```
$rawdata1 = read_file($file1, {binmode => ':raw'}) or die "...";
$rawdata2 = read_file($file2, {binmode => ':raw'}) or die "...";

my $json1 = decode_json NFD($rawdata1);
my $json2 = decode_json NFD($rawdata2);
```

To make this process slightly faster (it should be plenty fast already, since the module uses fast XS procedures), you can find out whether one of the two data files is already in a certain normalization form, and then leave that file unchanged, and convert the other file into that form.

For example:

```
$rawdata1 = read_file($file1, {binmode => ':raw'}) or die "...";
$rawdata2 = read_file($file2, {binmode => ':raw'}) or die "...";

if (checkNFD($rawdata1)) {
    # then you know $file1 is already in Normalization Form D
    # (i.e., it was formed by canonical decomposition).
    # so you only need to convert $file2 into NFD
    $rawdata2 = NFD($rawdata2);
}
my $json1 = decode_json $rawdata1;
my $json2 = decode_json $rawdata2;
```

Of course, you would naturally have to experiment now in the development time to see if one or other of the input files is already in a normalized form, and then in your final version of the code, you would no longer need a conditional statement, but simply convert the other input file into the same normalized form.

Also note that it is suggested to produce output in NFC form (if your program produces any output that would be stored and used later). See here, for example: http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/05/perlunicookbook-unicode-normalization.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the: `decode_json NFD(read_file( "nfd.json", { binmode => ':raw' } ))` doesn't works. Get error message: `Wide character in subroutine entry at read2.pl line 18.` Complaining the `decode_json`.

Comment: Yes, problems like this are tedious and often simple solutions that should work don't work. Let me mull over it and see if I can diagnose it for you (I'm trying to juggle SO and a tutoring center right now). This question is just like what I deal with nearly on a weekly basis, lots of unexpected quirks that show the world still is not quite perfect yet with regards to Unicode--although when I point out that reality, I just get a bunch of downvotes like here :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594636/using-html-symbol-entities-instead-of-the-actual-symbol/16594962#16594962 .

Comment: I suggest you use NFC as your normalization then before passing to decode_json. Try that.

Comment: @JosephMyers, do not bother because of the downvotes. There are always fanboys and people who will not admit they are wrong. You should tell your opinion without fear of downvotes. You might be right even if the whole world thinks you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I can't advice you some better "programming" solution. But why simply doesn't run

```
perl -CSDA -MUnicode::Normalize -0777 -nle 'print NFD($_)' < freebsd.json >bsdok.json
perl -CSDA -MUnicode::Normalize -0777 -nle 'print NFD($_)' < osx.json     >osxok.json
```

and now your script can read and use both because they are both in the same normalisation? So instead searching for som programming solution *inside* of your script, solve the problem before entering to the script. (The second command is unnecessary - simple convert on the file level. Sure is more easy as traversing data structures...

Answer (score -1):

Instead of traversing the data structure manually, let a module handle this for you.

- [Data::Visitor](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aVisitor)
- [Data::Rmap](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aRmap)
- [Data::Dmap](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDmap)