# Why won't the first few words within html tag print?

Tags: html

This is driving me crazy. Im just trying to print my name at the bottom of a webpage, Ryan Doe. If i put

```
<div><p>&#169; Ryan Doe 2014</p></div>
```

It will only print "Doe 2014"

If i put some random text in front, like:

```
<div><p>WHAYSJAFHSKJh&#169; Ryan Doe 2014</p></div>
```

It will print the entire string, like "WHAYSJAFHSKJh© Ryan Doe 2014". Whats going on?

The only style rules i am applying to this particular div are:

```
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
color: white;
```

Comment: Works completely fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DQH9g/

Comment: What happens if you just use `&copy;`? What font(s) are you using in your print style?

Comment: Same thing happens with using &copy. Applying a max-width in the stylesheet causes all the text to appear, I have no idea whats going on...

Comment: Create a fiddle which reproduces the problem.  There are to many variables which could cause this for us to be able to guess given the little HTML code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways may fix your problem:

1. try to use tag `<pre>` instead of `<p>`. `<pre>` is tag to display preformatted text.
2. try to add `&nbsp;` before `&#169`;

Answer (score 0):

HTML entities are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436637/1439168). Use the actual symbol `©`.

```html
   <div><p>© Ryan Doe 2014</p></div>
```