# "Â" appearing when "£" is used in a h3 tag

Tags: html

I am getting really confused because when I include a pound sign within an `<h3>` tag, the Â character appears before it. Any help with removing it?

```
<div align="right" style="margin-right: 300px;">
    <p>
        <h2>£25.00</h2>
    </p>
</div>
```

The output to screen appears as "Â£25.00" - I can't screenshot it as it crashes my pc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the £ since it is a special character. Instead of typing it as '£', use the character entity `&pound;`

So your tag should look like

```
<h2>&pound;25.00</h2>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I never knew about this and you have helped a bunch

Comment: why do you not have to use a character entity for $?

Comment: To piggy back off this, any special character will need to be escaped with a unicode solution, html cannot process special characters. You can find the unicode index [here](http://unicode.org/charts/charindex.html).

Your solution above, my mistake, is done in HTML entities, so [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) is the list for them as well.

To answer your previous question, you *should* use entities on all of your special characters.

Comment: You can check this other [S/O question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities) for an more indepth explanation of when and why they are used.

Answer (score 1):

It looks You edit text in UTF-8 and display it in WINDOWS-1252. You should change display to the former.

To set encoding for display You *can* add `<meta charset='utf-8'>` to the top of the head of html. You should however set the encoding on server too.