# Is there any reason to use HTML entities over the characters themselves?

Tags: html, encoding, html-entities

For example, suppose I want to put an en dash in my page title, like this:

```
Home – My Site
```

Is there any reason to use `&ndash;` over just putting the character `–` in my HTML file?

Comment: Depends on the character. If it's something super weird, you might run into issues. A simple dash, however, should not break anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Should One Use HTML Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely needed if you want to render characters that will mess up the HTML parser (`<` and `>`, and the `&` itself).

If you set the character set to UTF-8, then you can use other raw UTF8 characters.

`<meta charset='utf-8'>`

However some older browsers don't understand this tag, so they might not render UTF-8 characters properly.

I also wanted to point out - HTML entities are sometimes used to tell the browser to render a concept, rather than a specific character. Some browsers prefer to render entities in a more readable way than a Unicode character, for example Lynx renders `&trade;` as `(tm)` instead of `™`

Answer (score 1):

> If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags. <sub>[W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)</sub>

The only other HTML entities I would probably ever use would be `&nbsp;` and `&amp;` unless a specific issue came about.

Answer (score 0):

If an HTML entity exists for the character you want to use, you should use the HTML entity.  That ensures it displays as intended.

http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=latin

Answer (score -1):

yes. some browsers and operating systems don't like it when you use the actual entity as it is... occasionally when typing a dash on a Mac it will just scramble or look like a void square on a Windows machine. its just safer to use the entity :D