# What is HTML source code encode like &#x1c3;

Tags: html, hex, encode

I visited some site and I noticed that the html its seem as encoded, like an hex character.

```
<meta name="description" content="&#x5d4;&#x5d9;&#x5e8;&#x5e9;&#x5dd;/&#x5d4;&#x5d9;&#/>
```

What is this and what for?

how can I do this in my HTML also ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not encryption. It's just HTML special symbols (*entities*). Here's a [W3School page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp) about that with their meaning.

[Here's](https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder) a site to decode and encode HTML entites. So this (`&#x5d4;&#x5d9;&#x5e8;&#x5e9;&#x5dd;/&#x5d4;&#x5d9;`) is meaning: `הירשם/הי`.

Comment: Ok, so what the point for making this for all the html html content?

Comment: @david2000 Here is an answer for [`When Should One Use HTML Entities
`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/436748/6714194).